# Webflux EndpointConfiguration RouterFunctions.route error

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I am facing an issue with my code when using the RouterFunctions.route method. The code is failing to compile, not sure what I am doing wrong

**error description :**

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method route(RequestPredicate, HandlerFunction<T>) in the type RouterFunctions is not 
     applicable for the arguments (RequestPredicate, handler::getById)
    - The type CustomerProfileHandler does not define getById(ServerRequest) that is applicable here
    - The method route(RequestPredicate, HandlerFunction<T>) in the type RouterFunctions is not 
     applicable for the arguments (RequestPredicate, handler::getById)
```

**Endpoint Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
public class CustomerProfileEndpointConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(CustomerProfileHandler handler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(i(GET("/customer/{customerId}")), handler::getById);   
    }

    private static RequestPredicate i(RequestPredicate target) {
        return new CaseInsensitiveRequestPredicate(target);
    }
```

**Handler Class**

```
@Component
public class CustomerProfileHandler {

    // <1>
    private final CustomerProfileService profileService;

    CustomerProfileHandler(CustomerProfileService profileService) {
        this.profileService = profileService;
    }

    // <2>
    Mono<ServerResponse> getById(ServerRequest r) {
        return defaultReadResponse(this.profileService.get(id(r)));
    }
 private static Mono<ServerResponse> defaultReadResponse(Publisher<CustomerProfile> profiles) {
        return ServerResponse
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .body(profiles, CustomerProfile.class);
    }

    private static String id(ServerRequest r) {
        return r.pathVariable("customerId");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO

your `Mono<ServerResponse> getById(ServerRequest r)`  should be a public one

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getById(ServerRequest r) {
    return defaultReadResponse(this.profileService.get(id(r)));
}
```

**reference doc:**

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/web/webflux-functional.adoc